# Typescript using Pick for getbyid in generic repository class

Tags: typescript, repository, abstract

So I have the following example, which works:

```js
const example = () => {
    const primaryKey: keyof Seller = `id`;
    type SellerPrimaryKeyOnly = Pick<Seller, typeof primaryKey>
    const sellerPrimaryKey: SellerPrimaryKeyOnly = {id: 2}
};
```

and tried to implement something like:

```js
export abstract class Repository<T> implements IRepository<T> {
    public entityMap: TableMap<T>;
    public primaryKey: keyof T;

    constructor(primaryKey: keyof T, entityMap: TableMap<T>) {
        this.entityMap = entityMap;
        this.primaryKey = primaryKey;
    };

    public async getById(id: Pick<T, typeof this.primaryKey>) {
        const query: Query<T> = new Query<T>(this.entityMap).select().where(id);
        const entity: T = await query.first();
        return entity;
    };
```

After creating the following repository:

```js
export class SellerRepository extends Repository<Seller> {

    constructor() {
        const primaryKey: keyof Seller = `id`;
        const sellerMap: SellerMap = new SellerMap();
        super(primaryKey, sellerMap);
    };
};
```

and trying to use the `getById` method:

```js
const main = async () => {
    const seller: Seller = await new SellerRepository().getById({id: 1})
    console.log(seller);
};
```

got the following error:

`Argument of type '{ id: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Pick<Seller, keyof Seller>'. Type '{ id: number; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<Seller, keyof Seller>': name, typets(2345)`

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjV13.png)

Is there any workaround?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I manage to make it work, don`t know if it is the best solution.

Abstract Repository know looks like:

```js
export abstract class Repository<T, PK extends (keyof T)[]> implements IRepository<T, PK> {
    public entityMap: TableMap<T>;

    constructor(entityMap: TableMap<T>) {
        this.entityMap = entityMap;
    };

    public async getById(primaryKeys: Pick<T, PK[number]>) {
        const query: Query<T> = new Query<T>(this.entityMap).select().where(primaryKeys);
        const entity: T = await query.first();
        return entity;
    };
};
```

and Seller Repository looks like:

```js
export class SellerRepository extends Repository<Seller, [`id`]> {
    constructor() {
        const sellerMap: SellerMap = new SellerMap();
        super(sellerMap);
    };
};
```

Any thoughts on improving it?

Thanks!